# LinkedIn Scraping Multiple Pages

Tags: search, scrapy, linkedin-api

I know there's dicussions whether scraping LinkedIn is allowed or not; but from following article:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/emmawoollacott/2019/09/10/linkedin-data-scraping-ruled-legal/#787286c31b54

I think it is safe to say that **scraping** publicly available data from LinkedIn is legal.

Now, I am trying to scrape job searches for a specific job title in a specific region.
So far so good, everything works, except for the limit of the amount of scraped jobs to be 25.

I am trying to use following trick:
Inside the URL I pass a keyword &start=X
with X going from 0, to 25, 50, and so on.

In browser, this allows me to go to the next page view and extract jobs from there.
However, using **scrapy** this method doesn't work.

The code is as follows:

```
res = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords={}&location={}&start=25'.format(job, location))

response = TextResponse(res.url, body=res.text, encoding='utf-8')

print("processing:" + response.url)
```

Output:

> processing:https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=0

Even if I hardcode it to 25 (page 2), it sets it to 0.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "in browser" ?. i've tried on Google Chrome and if you specify start=some_number it redirects you to start=0. Could you describe the steps you took in browser to visualize the result starting at 25?

Comment: For me it doesn't, also google Chrome. I merely copy this link for example:

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=25

Comment: What specifically do you see. When you go down, to see more jobs, do you see page numbers or "click to see more jobs"?

Comment: Yep i see the more jobs, but it doesn't to anything in my case, and if i change the url to start=25 it redirects me to start=0.

Comment: Ok, I think it depends on region then! 
I am in Belgium and I don't see "more jobs", I see page numbers.

However the scrapy views lets me see "more jobs" (view(response)). I think that's why it works for me and not for you, nor scrapy

Comment: It may show a diffrent content depending on geolocation and useragent. Try setting a different useragent for scrappy (the same as your browser)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure on how this would work or what useragent I would need. When you hover over the "more jobs" button, is there any href keyword specified to load more jobs?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Just disable RedirectMiddleware with a REDIRECT_ENABLED=0 setting on the scrapy shell.

```
scrapy shell -s REDIRECT_ENABLED=0 "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=75"
```

_

```
2019-10-24 21:50:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (303) <GET https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=75> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x0684AB30>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=75>


In [2]: fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=50')
2019-10-24 21:56:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (303) <GET https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=50> (referer: None)

In [3]: fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=100')
2019-10-24 21:56:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (303) <GET https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Data+Scientist&location=Brussels&start=100> (referer: None)
```

For example, if you want the redirect middleware to ignore 301 and 302 responses (and pass them through to your spider) you can do this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]
```

This middleware handles redirection of requests based on response status.
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect